# dosfsck seems to be hanging

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fsck, fat32

When I run

`sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/disk2s2`

It just seems to be hanging after the initial log message. It is doing a very low disk I/O (reads 50MB in an hour) and close to 0 CPU usage. Below is the logs I got:

```
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  71:42/55, 72:45/4e, 73:48/54, 74:20/49, 75:20/54, 76:20/4c, 77:20/45
  , 78:20/44
  Not automatically fixing this.
Boot sector contents:
System ID "BSD  4.4"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
     32768 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
 244100096 bytes per FAT (= 476758 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 488216576 (sector 953548)
  61024972 data clusters (1999666282496 bytes)
32 sectors/track, 255 heads
    409640 hidden sectors
3906551768 sectors total
```

Note that my disk is in FAT32 format. Is this normal? When can I expect it to finish? Is there a way to see its progress?

Comment: Could be the use of -a and -l together. -a means fix things without user input by choosing the least destructive approach when there is a choice. -l means ask the user when there is a choice to be made. Not sure what happens when you specify both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the `-t` flag it started working.